# Moved application to Library, now com.google.ads.adview doesn't work

Tags: android

I had a working Android app that I built in Eclipse. I'm in the process of making a free version of the app and so I moved to existing app into a library (I checked the "IsLibrary" button) - then I created a "Free" project with the intent to reference the now new library.

I have an error though -

I've got this:

```
   <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    ads:adUnitId="a14e11c5fc50399"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"/>
```

And `AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);` to reference it from an activity. It says "adView cannot be resolved". *I added the google admob jar to my new library, but still no-go there.*

There must be something about using a jdk within a library that I've missed.

Any tips?

Comment: Is this layout snippet from the library or the project using the library? Is the associated Java code from the library or the project using the library?

Comment: All code shown is from the library project. In fact if I turn off the library feature it compiles and runs as iam

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the admob jar needed in the library project is in the "Free" project classpath as well

Comment: That was one of the first things I did actually, but no go for me.